# How to offset a string in MIPS assembly language so only the substring will be printed?

Tags: assembly, mips

So I'm struggling to understand how to offset a string after taking the user's input of the index. I'm not sure which instruction in MIPS to use.

This is my code so far:

```
.data

string: .space 51 # reserves the next specified number of bytes for 
string and includes the byte for the null terminate

prompt_string: .asciiz "Enter a string: "

prompt_index: .asciiz "Enter the index: "

prompt_substring: .asciiz "The substring is: "

.text

li $v0, 4

la $a0, prompt_string # address of the prompt we want

syscall

li $v0, 8

la $a0, string

li $a1, 50 # maximum numbers of bytes to read of the string

syscall

li $v0, 4

la $a0, prompt_index

syscall

li $v0, 5

syscall

move $t0, $v0

li $v0, 4

la $a0, prompt_substring

syscall

li $v0, 4

la $a0, string

li $v0, 10

syscall
```

Comment: `add $a0, $a0, something`, to add to the address after an `la $a0, string`.

Comment: A C-style string (or some assembly), is a series of consecutive bytes terminated with a nul-character.  Strings, like most things, are refereed to by the lowest address. i.e. for strings, the address of the first byte of the string.  If you refer to an address past the first byte yet still within the string, that will cut off the beginning, while still leaving a valid nul-terminated string.  However, while we can skip initial characters of the string using pointer arithmetic, we cannot exclude characters from the end of the string in any similar manner, so that is a more complicated operation.

Comment: In other languages strings are represented by a pair: a pointer to first byte and a length,  so two values are used but no nul-terminator is needed.  Using this representation, we can exclude initial and/or final characters fairly easily, but it still takes real work (making a copy) to exclude characters from within the middle of the string, or to add characters beginning, middle, or end.